# ArcGIS Server map service layer placed in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins, layers, arcgis-rest-api, map-service, qgis-2.18

I try to load this ArcGIS Server map service layer https://gwa.israntique.org.il/mobidic/rest/services/landuse/MapServer/0 into QGIS 2.18.

When I do it with "ArcGIS REST API Connector" plugin, with the option of "only request feature overlapping the current view extent" the computer stuck:

[image]

and I must restart the QGIS, whereas in ArcGIS desktop the layer works fine.

Comment: Is your Projection CRS set to `EPSG:2039`?

Comment: yes, my projection CRS set to EPSG:2039

Answer (score 1):

The CRS doesn't matter, the plugin works in 2039 as well.
The problem is probably the extent. Since the REST query is limited to 1000 features, The plugin will fail to get more than 1000 of them, but will still try and read all the features in the extent.

QGIS isn't stuck, there are some 240000 features in the layer, and you haven't detailed the extent in which you are working.

Try zooming in on the required area, applying a filter, or use a different method of extracting the data from the service